# Velocity NumberTools formatter

Tags: velocity, number-formatting, formatter

I need to format a Number with Velocity using commas as decimal separator an dot as thousand separator.

I checked for other answer, but I could find only this:
[How to use Velocity NumberTool for big currency numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339988/how-to-use-velocity-numbertool-for-big-currency-numbers)
which is not useful for my purpose, since in case i want to use different styles i need to create different functions.

I also checked the Velocity documentation and use different type of patterns, none of them working for me:

```
context.put("numberTool", new NumberTool());

$numberTool.format('#.###,00', $val)
$numberTool.format('###.###,00', $val)
$numberTool.format('#.###,##', $val)
$numberTool.format('###.###,##', $val)
```

Can somebody help me and find a way using if possible the Velocity Number Format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the locale of the NumberTool. For instance:

```
[java]
NumberTool numberTool = new NumberTool();
numberTool.setLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
context.put("numberTool", numberTool);

[vtl]
$numberTool.format('#,###.00', $val)
$numberTool.format('###,###.00', $val)
$numberTool.format('#,###.##', $val)
$numberTool.format('###,###.##', $val)
```

Comment: But `##` is a comment in Velocity.

Comment: @Alex78191 Not inside literal quoted strings, hopefully. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Else if you dont have access to change the locale you could do another trick thanks to String.

```
-- To get $50000.00 to be $50,000.00 do (we need to convert to double)
#set($NumberFormatter = "")
$NumberFormatter.format("$%,.2f",$convert.toDouble($someNumberWithDigits))

-- To get $50000 to be $50,000 and no decimals do (we need to convert to int)
#set($NumberFormatter = "")
$NumberFormatter.format("$%,d",$convert.toInteger($someNumberWithDigits))
```